# Compile Error "Variable not defined" in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and trying to solve a problem in VBA Excel. I am using "Option Explicit". Every time I run code in VBA a compile error appears. It says "variable not defined". How a variable is defined in VBA?

[image]

Comment: You are getting that error because your variable is not declared and you have used `Option Explicit` at the top which forces you to declare your variables as a specific data type. You may want to read up about it in [To ‘Err’ is Human](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2017/12/15/to-err-is-human/). See Point #2. Also when working with Excel rows, it is better to declare them as `Long` rather than `Integer` else you may get `Overflow` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic ...:

```
Dim i As Long
```

So, you need to study a primer "Beginning with VBA" or similar.

Comment: It is advisable to use `Long` rather than `Integer` when you are working with rows in Excel. `Dim i As Long`